# Pass Firebase Config to Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My root firebase config code is in a file called FirebaseConfig.js. I want to be able to access the data that is configured there, from container components throughout my app, in order to configure child ref's specific to said child components.

**FirebaseConfig.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class FirebaseConfig extends Component {
  render() {  
    const config = {...
    };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  // INIT DB REFERENCE
  const db = firebase.database();
  const dbRef = db.ref();
  // INIT STORAGE REFERENCE
  const storage = firebase.storage();
  const storageRef = storage.ref();
  console.log("FB INIT'D with STORAGE REF: " + storageRef);

  return FirebaseConfig; 
    }
  }
 export default FirebaseConfig;
```

**File Structure**

```
src
 |__App.js
 |__index.js
 |__FirebaseConfig.js
 |__ /Home
     |__ Home.js
     |__ HomeContainer.js  //Want to access Config var's here
```

Is it possible to configure the Firebase app like this, and if so - is it a good pattern?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to configure the Firebase app like this, and if so - is
>   it a good pattern?

I don't think it is a good pattern.

In my opinion you should keep firebase instance outside react components. Use `redux` instead to store your `firebase` data. Dispatch an `action` to populate reducer and `@connect` your data with your react components.

You should definitely check `@r-park`'s [firebase todo app project](https://github.com/r-park/todo-react-redux) to have better understanding. Well organized and planned. I used it as a base for one of my small projects.

Comment: thanks, although I'm looking for a way that avoids using redux as I have a limited time frame to finishing this project and think it would take too long to learn it.

Comment: @SamYoungNY If you already know how to setup react then redux is for you. Read some tutorials, even watch youtube videos, good quality content there. Redux is really simple, it's a common pattern for react. BUT and I am very serious now. Firebase can be a problem for you, if you don't know it well. I switched from firebase to GraphCool(GraphQL PaaS) when I started building a project for my company. If you are at the point of picking database provider I would suggest you switching to GraphCool!